# Migrating to iOS 5 Core Data new APIs: understand NSConfinementConcurrencyType

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm slowly migrating to iOS 5 Core Data new APIs and I'm investigating about `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`.

From Apple documentation

> Confinement (NSConfinementConcurrencyType). This is the default. You
> promise that context will not be used by any thread other than the one
> on which you created it. (This is exactly the same threading
> requirement that you've used in previous releases.)

The thing is not really obvious to me is the meaning of *default* in this context. What it does really mean?

Usually, if I need to perform a really long import operation in CD, I set up a new `NSOperation` class and the I create its own context.

```
- (void)main
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

    // other code here...
}
```

Now, I can take advantage of parent context and do the following:

```
- (void)main
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [moc setParentContext:[self masterMoc]];

    // other code here...
}
```

Said this, what about `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`? What could be a typical usage example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "default," Apple means that this is the standard way Core Data MOCs have always worked. The MOC must be created on the thread upon which it is used. In your code above, you are following the standard historically effective MOC usage pattern. The other styles of MOCs create and manage their own background queues or bind to the main queue. This can simplify things somewhat. Or not. Primarily, they are block oriented interfaces to the MOC. Sometimes that is nice to have. (While blocks are the new hotness, they are not an unalloyed good. I have seen block oriented code that is written by lazy programmers. They leave way too much complexity in their methods. Maintenance of such code can be quite hard with subtle interactions.)

The idea of a parent context is orthogonal to that of thread confinement. The parent context is one way to quickly associate most of the parameters needed by a MOC. (Apple is unclear what is actually carried across between the MOCs. Nor do they discuss merge policy issues.) You still have to catch, I believe, the inter-MOC notifications.

If I may suggest, don't over think these things. The changes to Core Data for Lion/iOSv5 were quite modest.

Comment: + 1 for your support. So, are saying that creating a context as I did in the second snippet it is the same to create a confinement context? Thanks.

Comment: With *The idea of a parent context is orthogonal to that of thread confinement.* are you saying that I need to continue to listen for notifications in the main thread or not? As I understood, when I save in a background context, the save are not written to disk but in memory. Does this save merge the two contexts?

Comment: Flex_Addicted, `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` is the default type of context. Hence, an `NSManagedObjectContext.new` creates one of that type. You need to use the more specific initializer, `-initWithConcurrencyType:`, to get any other type of MOC. Andrew

Comment: Flex_Addicted,  W.r.t. `-save:`, it always persists its data. `-save:` is the only way I know of to communicate between MOCs. Hence, you still need to listen for the notifications. A child's MOC does not create its objects in the parent MOC. For example, you can create child MOCs that manipulate objects and then throw away the changes. The parent MOC is not affected. (There is the concept of rebasing objects between MOCs. I use this when I want to return which objects were selected in the background, but no values to the parent MOC. [Do this by an objectID to object conversion.]) Andrew